# Struts unable to find action class

Tags: java, xml, struts2, struts-config

Been banging my head for quiet sometime now as I don't seem to understand why struts is unable to find my action class.

This is my struts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.mypackage.actions.TutotrialAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

This is my project structure
[image]

And finally this is the error that I see
[image]

Clearly the action seem to be present, not sure why it is unable to find it. Another eye ball would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small typo:

```
<action name="getTutorial" class="org.mypackage.actions.TutotrialAction" method="execute">
                                                            ^
```

should be

```
<action name="getTutorial" class="org.mypackage.actions.TutorialAction" method="execute">
```

Comment: am blinded, I dont seem to see the typo

Comment: thanks but I still end up with `Caused by: Action class [org.mypackage.actions.TutorialAction] not found - action`

Comment: Are you sure that the class is packaged in the war file?

Comment: Good lord help Tawheed! Just realized that I had to build first before running on the server. Pretty odd since am coming from a Rails background. But thank you soo much!